# Rooting my phone and installing CyanogenMod. Can I ever go back?

Tags: rooting, htc-sense

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to unroot a device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1934/unroot-a-device-without-wiping)
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I have a HTC Desire HD with HTC Sense and I was thinking of rooting my phone, and installing CyanogenMod but I wonder... If I regret it later on, is there a possibility for me to go back to HTC Sense?

Comment: I think the duplicate should cover this.  As noted it depends on the method you use.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention about installing the Mod. its not just about rooting.

Comment: Oh yes, you ought to be able to flash the original firmware back.  You could use [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/1465) to help you find the firmware ahead of time so you know you have the option. Another method would be to make a Nandroid backup before installing CM, which is easily restored -- Brian mentions this in a comment on his answer to the other question.

Comment: I didnt find where to get HTC sense in that post

Comment: HTC sense is just the name of the UI.  You need a full ROM for the Desire HD (which will contain Sense), just like CyanogenMod is a full ROM.