# Rooting introduced adware; how to get rid of that (if needed including unroot)?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, boot, tablet, unrooting, lenovo

I have Lenovo Android tablet and I rooted using Kingo root. After rooting my device I started getting unwanted ads. So I unrooted the device using some Google references. But still I'm getting the same ads in my device.

Please help me getting rid of those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to unroot a device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1934/is-it-possible-to-unroot-a-device)

Comment: @iBug possibly not. Though it might seem so on a quick glance, if you take a closer look the question is rather "how to get rid of those ads". OP even states already having unrooted (I've just slightly edited the post to make it clearer).

Answer (score 0):

By rooting the smartphone usually only an app (like [SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu)) to manage these rights installed is installed. However, the apps do not display ads.

However, Kingo root might install additional apps during the rooting, which might then display ads.

In a first step, you should uninstall all (Not system) apps that are not used.

If the advertisement is still displayed, further apps should be gradually excluded, for this they can also be uninstalled.

If this is about in App advertising, it may be because an update has added advertising. To remove this type of advertising, an adblocker can be installed.

Comment: Oops... LOL. OK, as you've updated that, I'm removing the comments now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Root shouldn't have caused any ads. I think because you used kingo root app that might have installed some virus as well as root. Best way to fix is to factory reset otherwise its hard to know what your problem is.

Comment: Certainly no virus (as such a thing doesn't exist on Android), but possibly some malware. Having root capabilities, I doubt a factory-reset will fix it, as it might be placed as system app – in which case the only thing that helps is flashing a clean ROM.

Comment: Does factory reset not restore it back to original state so system apps are gone? Well learned a new thing lol

Comment: Only partly. For details, check with our [factory-reset tag-wiki](/tags/factory-reset/info). A common misconseption: A factory-reset neither restores to the Android version the device shipped with if there was an update applied already. Note the full term is "Restore to factory ***settings*** –" not to "factory state". So all your settings (incl. data and user-installed apps plus cache) are gone, but that's it.